# ivy repository not getting updated using sbt publish-local

Tags: sbt, ivy

I am publishing a jar file to my local Ivy repository using publish-local (which has worked for me in the past).  Sbt version is 0.13.9. Even though I am not getting any exceptions when I publish the jar file, my local Ivy repository is not getting updated (I have to remove the ivy.xml file inside my cache directory in order for the process to work correctly).  The same issue was replicated on another computer so its not specific to my computer.  I have copied snippets of the sbt build file.  Any thoughts on what might be causing the issue to surface?

```
organization := "com.test"

name := "test123"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

crossPaths := false

autoScalaLibrary := false

resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "conf"

javacOptions in (Compile) ++= Seq("-Xdoclint:none")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
)


libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.18"
  )
}
```

I removed some of the dependencies in the build file.  I run the following every time:

```
sbt clean reload compile publish-local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using the following plugin:

```
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dirty-money
```

This allowed the older published artifact to be removed from the local ivy repository.